# EWS fails on update

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using EWS Managed API to read and send emails. However, when I try to set the IsRead property on a specific EmailMessage, I get the following exception on the Update method:

> The expected XML node type was Element, but the actual type is
>   EndElement.

Here is the method I use to update the IsRead property:

```
public void UpdateExchangeEmail(string _ID, bool _isRead)
{
  EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(ExchService, _ID);
  message.IsRead = _isRead;
  message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.NeverOverwrite);
}
```

Where ExchService is the ExchangeService object and works fine for reading and sending emails. What's really odd is that the value of IsRead is set properly, so it seems to work despite the fact that an exception is thrown.

Any input on how to fix it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I bellieve you have to call the .Load() method before you can access this kind of properties

```
public void UpdateExchangeEmail(string _ID, bool _isRead)
{
  EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(ExchService, _ID);
  message.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead)); // Do this first.
  message.IsRead = _isRead;
  message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.NeverOverwrite);
}
```